# Netdiscover not showing desired output in Docker container

Tags: python, docker

I'm using Netdiscover tool for live host identification.
When I use it in my terminal,using

```
sudo netdiscover -r "network_range"
```

I get the following output.
[image]

As it can be seen, there are 4 devices detected.

When I run the same command for Netdiscover inside a Docker Container, I get the following output
[image]

This only shows 1 device being detected.

I have confirmed that all the devices are discoverable, but still not been able to figure out the issue.
What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Docker containers are isolated from your machine

Comment: I am aware of that. But shouldn't docker pick the networks? If some devices are connected on the same network, and so is the system, then it must pick up those devices as well. No?

Comment: It was working well until a few days ago, but suddenly this issue appears